# Integration of $2$-form on the sphere using the stereographic projection

Tags: integration, differential-forms, pullback

Let $\omega$ be the $2$ form $\omega = x \, dy \wedge dz - y \, dx \wedge dz + z \, dx \wedge dy$ on $S^2$. I want to integrate $\int_{S^2} \omega$ using the definition, with the stereographic projection ${\varphi}^{- 1} : {\mathbb{R}}^2 \to S^2 \setminus \{(0 , 0 , 1)\}$ given by
$$
{\varphi}^{- 1}(u , v) = \left(x = \frac{2 u}{1 + u^2 + v^2} , y = \frac{2 v}{1 + u^2 + v^2} , z = \frac{u^2 + v^2 - 1}{1 + u^2 + v^2}\right).
$$
Then
$$
\int_{S^2} \omega = \int_{{\mathbb{R}}^2} {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(\omega).
$$
I proceed to calculate ${({\varphi}^{- 1})}^*(\omega)$. It is
$$
{\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(\omega) = x {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dy) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dz) - y {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dx) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dz) + z {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dx) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dy).
$$
For instance,
$$
{\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dx) = \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \, du + \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \, dv = \frac{2 (1 + u^2 + v^2) - 4 u^2}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^2} \, du - \frac{4 u v}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^2} \, dv
$$
and similarly
$$
{\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dy) = - \frac{4 u v}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^2} \, du + \frac{2 (1 + u^2 + v^2) - 4 v^2}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^2} \, dv
$$
and
$$
{\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dz) = 4 \left(\frac{u}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^2} \, du + \frac{v}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^2} \, dv\right).
$$
We calculate now the exterior products:
$$
x {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dy) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dz) = - \frac{16 u^2}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^4} \, du \wedge dv,
$$
$$
- y {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dx) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dz) = - \frac{16 v^2}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^4} \, du \wedge dv,
$$
$$
z {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dx) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dy) = - 4 \frac{{(u^2 + v^2)}^2 - 2 (u^2 + v^2) + 1}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^4} \, du \wedge dv.
$$
Therefore
$$
{\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(\omega) = \frac{4}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^4} (- 2 u^2 - 2 v^2 - 1 - u^4 - 2 u^2 v^2 - v^4) \, du \wedge dv
$$
if I did not have any mistake. But how can I proceed with this expression? On the other hand, I know that the integral should be $4 \pi$.

Comment: Yeah, you have a mistake. Have you used some CAS to help with this horrendous algebra? P.S. It might help a little to use polar coordinates on the plane.

Comment: Where is my mistake? No I have not used anyone

Comment: I'm not checking your work, but I have done this computation before and your third term is clearly wrong. It should simplify reasonably well.

Comment: Do you mean $z {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dx) \wedge {\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dy)$ or simply ${\left({\varphi}^{- 1}\right)}^*(dz)$?

Comment: The pullback computations are correct, but the sum of the three should simplify drastically. Can you factor your numerator?

Comment: But I reiterate my suggestion that you consider polar coordinates (in the future?) when you see expression that are radially symmetric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results so far are actually all correct. To proceed, you just need to be a little less eager in expanding all the expressions, but opt for factoring more. In particular, the result for $(\phi^{-1})^* (z\, dx\wedge dy)$ can be factored. The numerator is actually just $4(u^2+v^2-1)^2$. When you add up the pullback of the other two terms, you are adding $16(u^2+v^2)$ to the numerator. Thus you get $4(u^2+v^2+1)^2$, which cancels neatly with the denominator.

Alternatively, if you are familiar enough with the expansion of $(x+y+z)^2$, you can recognize straight away that the numerator of your final result is $4(u^2+v^2+1)^2$.

To proceed with the integral, you can either convert the integral into polar coordinates in the $uv$-plane, or do it with trig substitutions. The former method is easier by far.

Comment: I understand what you mean, thank you. But my numerator is $- 4 {(u^2 + v^2 + 1)}^2$, It can be cancelled with denominator, but it is negative for me. Why is it not for you?

Comment: Ah, I just treated the negative sign as a factor in front of the whole expression and left it there without mentioning it. The full expression for $(\phi^{-1})^*\omega$ should be $-4/(u^2+v^2+1)^2$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah ok, but on the other hand if it is negative,
$$
\int_{S^2} \omega = - 4 \int_{{\mathbb{R}}^2} \frac{1}{{(1 + u^2 + v^2)}^2} = - 4 \int_0^{2 \pi} \left(\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\rho}{{(1 + {\rho}^2)}^2} \, d \rho\right) \, d \theta = - 4 \pi.
$$
But it should be $4 \pi$ instead I guess, no?

Comment: This is because [the stereographic projection out of the north pole reverses orietation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1649194/does-stereographic-projection-preserve-or-reverse-orientation). You can kind of see this from visualizing how the patch near the south pole gets projected. The "inside" of the sphere is now to "top side" of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much